# How to instantiate multiple instances of the same generic protocol with different types in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a generic protocol P, and I want other class B to have different instances of this protocol with different types. I want to simulate the following behavior:

```
protocol P<T> {
    func getAll() -> [T]
}

class B {
    var foo1: P<Int>

    var foo2: P<String>
}
```

How can I accomplish this in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with protocols in Swift. You can do something similar:

```
protocol P {
    typealias T
    func getAll() -> [T]
}

class C : P {
    typealias T = Int
    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return []
    }
}

class D : P {
    typealias T = String
    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return []
    }
}

struct B {
    var foo1: C
    var foo2: D
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me because I want foo1 and foo2 be of different classes implementing the protocol

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't help you, but this is the closest you're going to get. Protocols in Swift can't have generics apart from an internal `typealias`.

Comment: Why not just use `var foo1: P` and let your instance tell `foo1` what type of item fills the generic requirement?

Comment: @IanMacDonald That won't work because the protocol has an associated type. Since types have to be complete at compile time, just `P` is not allowed.

Comment: You're right. For some reason my playground didn't complain at me.

Comment: @IanMacDonald What I want to do is implement the Repository Pattern, but since the repositories for all the different objects that I want to store have the same functions, I would like to implement just one generic protocol, instead of one for each type

Comment: I understood *why* you want to do this. What I'm telling you is that Swift doesn't allow you to have generics in protocols. The closest you can get is a `typealias`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
protocol P {
    typealias T
    func getAll() -> [T]
}

extension Int: P {
    func getAll() -> [Int] {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    }
}

extension String: P {
    func getAll() -> [String] {
        return ["foo", "bar", "zoo"]
    }
}

class B {
    var foo1: Int = 0

    var foo2: String = ""
}

let x = B()
x.foo1.getAll()
x.foo2.getAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
protocol P {
    typealias T
    func getAll() -> [T]
}

class IntGetter: P {
    typealias T = Int
    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return [1,2,3]
    }
}

class StringGetter: P {
    typealias T = String
    func getAll() -> [T] {
        return ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
}

let i = IntGetter()
i.getAll() // [1,2,3]

let s = StringGetter()
s.getAll() // ["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: See the discussion above